# How to access winform textbox control from another tab?

Tags: c#

I have few tabs and I need to way to access textboxes on them easily, I tried code below:

```
textBox1.Text = otherTab.textBox1.Text;
String textIneed =otherTab.textBox1.Text;
```

I did make the TextBox public but Visual Studio insists there is no reference to TextBox...Also the tabs are on the same form.

Comment: you should get it simply via name of the `TextBox`

Comment: how can there be two textBox1 in a single form?

Comment: MS example for two forms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the tabs are on the same form.

And all UI elements are declared on the same form, so simply address it as `this.TheTextBoxName.Text`.

Answer (score 0):

Any control declared on a form will be the child of the form, and any control can access another control inside the form childs. So, here no need to declare any control as public or provide the tab name as object referrence. Simply write like below

```
String textIneed = textBox1.Text;
```